# Does it need Monodevelop's old version that compile mono-develop 3.1.0 version?

Tags: mono, monodevelop

When I compile Monodevelop 3.1.0 for macosx from source in terminal,it failed.But when I open the 'MonoDevelop.mdw' using Monodevelo 2.8.2,using 'Run' function to build it,then it runs.But why?

### Errors As follows:

```
Last login: Tue Jun 12 09:22:05 on console
starmatoMacBook-Pro:~ star$ cd /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop
starmatoMacBook-Pro:monodevelop star$ make runcd main && make run
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/local-config:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="" MONO_GAC_PREFIX="/usr/local:" MONODEVELOP_LOCALE_PATH="./build/locale" MONO_ADDINS_REGISTRY="./build/bin" UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 exec -a "monodevelop" /usr/bin/mono --debug ./build/bin/MonoDevelop.exe
ERROR [2012-06-12 10:18:40Z]: Error setting process name
System.DllNotFoundException: libc.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime:prctl (int,byte[],intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.unixSetProcessName (System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/Runtime.cs:257 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.SetProcessName (System.String name) [0x00010] in /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/Runtime.cs:240 
ERROR [2012-06-12 10:18:41Z]: Error initialising GLib logging.
System.DllNotFoundException: libglib-2.0.0.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Marshaller:g_malloc (uintptr)
  at GLib.Marshaller.StringToPtrGStrdup (System.String str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Log.SetLogHandler (System.String logDomain, LogLevelFlags flags, GLib.LogFunc logFunc) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.GLibLogging.set_Enabled (Boolean value) [0x00030] in /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/GLibLogging.cs:50 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x00056] in /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:88 
FATAL ERROR [2012-06-12 10:18:41Z]: MonoDevelop failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run MonoDevelop (for example gtk-sharp, gnome-sharp or gtkhtml-sharp) may not be properly installed in the GAC.
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Application ---> System.DllNotFoundException: glibsharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) GLib.Thread:glibsharp_g_thread_supported ()
  at GLib.Thread.get_Supported () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) [0x0007e] in /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:95 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0004f] in /Users/star/Surer/DevKits/Mono/mono-monodevelop-git/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:503 
make[1]: *** [runmd] Error 255
make: *** [run] Error 2
starmatoMacBook-Pro:monodevelop star$
```

Comment: I think you should ask on the monodevelop mailing list - http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/monodevelop-list

Comment: What does it say in the terminal window when monodevelop fails?

Answer (score 1):

Your DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH environment variable is broken. You can fix it with:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_FALLBACK_PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I don't have the PATH like "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib",because my mono was compiled by me hand by hand.So the error still there using your instrution...

Comment: Then you'll have to set the environment appropriately for your Mono installation. I would recommend you look at http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments